# ExecutorService awaitTermination shutdown signal in the Runnable instance

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I've a few questions around `ExecutorService` and the shutdown process.
My use case:
I use an `ExecutorService` to spawn a fixed number of threads whose run method look like this:

```
while (true) {
   try {
      this.currentThreadRunning = true;
      processMessage();
   }
   catch (Throwable e) {
      // Keeping the thread alive despite exceptions.
   }
}
```

These threads run infinitely, polling for messages.

What am I trying to do?
I am polling an SQS queue for messages and processing them.

Obviously, in my case, the `ExecutorService's` shutdown method would not work. When `shutdownNow()` is called, all my threads are shutdown unceremoniously. I hate it!

Is there a way to invoke `awaitTermination` and verify, in my `Runnable` instance(in a finally block?), if shutdown has been initiated and trigger the same for the current thread?

UPDATE: I've refactored my code to perform polling and then spawning threads to process them. Thus, the Runnable instance's run method need not be an endless loop. And `awaiTermination` will lead to a definite closure of the threads. And to be sure, I've triggered `shutdownNow` after `awaitTermination`.

Comment: In order to spawn an infinite number of threads, you need an infinite number of CPU cores and memory. Do you have that?

Comment: The usual usage of an executor would be to create a new task for every message to process.

Comment: @Sleiman - There are a fixed number of threads. But they run infinitely. I'll update the question to reflect the scenario accordingly.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker - If I spawn a new thread for every message, it translates to this - one thread polls for messages and then spawns a thread. Or I can spawn a fixed number of threads & allow each of them to poll for messages & process the received message. Scalability-wise, I prefer the second approach.

Comment: @user657592 This now looks much like the producer consumer pattern. Have a thread to poll messages and a fixed size thread pool to process them. Maybe you should also have a look at jms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are doing is conceptually wrong.

`awaitTermination` is meant to wait for all threads to finish naturally and then stop the executor. When submitting a `Runnable`, it shouldn't have an idea of the context of it's execution, so, coupling your runnable to your executor is not a good idea IMHO.

Maybe you should look into the `Future` class and move your `Runnable` implementation there. Then you will be forced to implement a `cancel(boolean)` method which you might find useful.

What is exactly your use case? Maybe if you explain it, the community can point out a better suited implementation.

Comment: I received a similar feedback. But, let me reiterate - I want a mechanism where I can check if a terminate request was issued from the `ExecutorService` in the Runnable method. - When a shutdown is signaled by the `ExecutorService` won't the thread be aware of it? I don't want to check if the `ExecutorService` has signaled a shutdown, but rather if the thread received such a signal. Agreed that it is a fine line.  But, your thoughts and opinion would help.

Comment: This is taken from the documentation of `shutdownNow()` - There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing actively executing tasks.  For example, typical implementations will cancel via {@link Thread#interrupt}, so any task that fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate. So, typically you should receive an interrupt. However, there is no guarantee that this would be the case. If you rely on that, you are tying your runnable logic to a specific executor implementation and you should consider if the trade - off is worth in your case.

Answer (score 0):

For infinitely running `Runnables` I rely on catching an `InterruptedException`, which will typically be thrown from my calling `shutdownNow()` or occasionally from calling `Future#cancel(true)`

```
while(!Thread.interrupted()) {
    try {

    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        break;
    } catch(Throwable e) {
        // Keeping the thread alive despite exception
    }
}
// Thread was interrupted via shutdownNow(), cleanup resources
```

If I need to distinguish between a resumable interrupt and a shutdown interrupt then I share an `AtomicBoolean doShutdown` among my `Runnables` that is initialized to `false` and set to `true` if I want an `InterruptedException` to terminate the thread.

Comment: you should restore the interrupted status after catching InterruptedException in order for calling code to also be able to handle interrupts.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the interrupt status of the thread you are running in (see tutorial on interrupts here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html). Your code should be:

```
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        try {
            this.currentThreadRunning = true;
            processMessage();
        }
        catch (Throwable e) {
            // Keeping the thread alive despite exceptions.
        }
}
```

Note however that you do have to handle interrupts correctly in code called from your runnable. If there is anything like the following:

```
try {
    // do something
} catch(InterruptedException e) {
    // ignore
}
```

then this won't work. The correct way to handle `InterruptedException` is to call `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();`.

Comment: Does `awaitTermination` send out an Interrupt to the threads?

Comment: no.. that does not. if you call shutdownNow then the thread will recieve interrupt

Answer (score 0):

You should not call `shutdownNow()` But you should only call shutdown and use `awaitTermination`  to wait for some time.

So shutdown would be something like this

Declare a volatile variable

```
private volatile stopThread = false;
```

On shutdown you call

```
 this.stopThread = true;
 executor.shutdown();
 executor.awaitTermination(..
 executor.shutdownNow() // in case termination takes too long
```

And in the thread you check for the stopThread variable. You cannot use isInterrupted here because we are not interrupting the thread. we are just waiting for the thread to exit based on this condition

```
if(stopThread){
 // calling off all the operations and returning 
}
```

I have written an article about shuting down the executorservice properly
http://programtalk.com/java/executorservice-not-shutting-down/
 I hope this will help you.